# Laravel 5: Check if post input query exists

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

In Laravel you can get all the post data like so:

```
$request->post();
```

You can also check if a form has the GET or POST query like so:

```
$request->has('foo');
```

However, how do I check if a form has a POST query. Note that I'm aware you can do the following:

```
$request->post('foo') !== null;
```

but foo can sometimes be null if the data being posted is JSON. e.g.

```
{
    "foo": null
}
```

Comment: Would `$request->isMethod('post') && $request->has('foo')` work for you?

Comment: No becuase users can send both GET queries and post data at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, a solution that I found worked quite well is as follows:

```
$postData = $request->post();
array_has($postData, 'foo');
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can also use dot notation like you can with `$request->has()`.

Any alternative solutions is welcome.